Is it possible to create custom code analyzers for F#
I would like to know if it is possible to add custom code analyzer for F# like you can for C# / VB# with Roslyn? Are there some frameworks/projects I can leverage to do it?
In addition, I would like to have an integration with Visual Studio to see errors from the analyzer in the code editor.

search for F# Analyzers
